# Update list of maps with function that returns tuple

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am using Elixir 1.8.0 and Ecto 3.0.7

I have a list of maps that that look like this

```
things = [
  %{
    availability_zone: "us-west-1a",
    dns_name: "ec2-13-45-67-46.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com",
    image_id: "ami-251234",
    instance_id: "i-1234",
    instance_state: "running",
    instance_type: "m4.large",
    ip_address: "13.45.67.46",
    key_name: "some_key",
    launch_time: "2018-06-13T16:34:04.000Z",
    monitoring: "disabled",
    private_ip_address: "10.1.1.1",
    vpc_id: "vpc-9999"
  },
  %{
    availability_zone: "us-west-1a",
    dns_name: "ec2-13-99-99-46.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com",
    image_id: "ami-2522344",
    instance_id: "i-99999",
    instance_state: "running",
    instance_type: "m4.large",
    ip_address: "13.99.99.99",
    key_name: "some_key",
    launch_time: "2018-06-13T16:34:04.000Z",
    monitoring: "disabled",
    private_ip_address: "10.1.1.2",
    vpc_id: "vpc-9999"
  }
]
```

I am attempting to insert this list into my database using `Ecto.Repo.insert_all`. This doesn't work as is, because I'm calling `launch_time` a `utc_datetime` and this is not a DateTime in my list.

I'm attempting to convert it to a DateTime, however, `from_iso8601` returns a tuple, which, of course, doesn't work.

```
iex(12)> things |> Enum.map(fn elem ->
...(12)>         Map.update!(elem, :launch_time, &DateTime.from_iso8601/1)
...(12)>       end)
[
  %{
    availability_zone: "us-west-1a",
    dns_name: "ec2-13-56-179-46.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com",
    image_id: "ami-25110f45",
    instance_id: "i-0df401bc2d3b16d37",
    instance_state: "running",
    instance_type: "m4.large",
    ip_address: "13.56.179.46",
    key_name: "salt_provisioning",
    launch_time: {:ok, #DateTime<2018-06-13 16:34:04.000Z>, 0},
    monitoring: "disabled",
    private_ip_address: "10.81.1.244",
    vpc_id: "vpc-07a5e160"
  },
  %{
    availability_zone: "us-west-1a",
    dns_name: "ec2-13-56-179-46.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com",
    image_id: "ami-25110f45",
    instance_id: "i-0df401bc2d3b16d37",
    instance_state: "running",
    instance_type: "m4.large",
    ip_address: "13.56.179.46",
    key_name: "salt_provisioning",
    launch_time: {:ok, #DateTime<2018-06-13 16:34:04.000Z>, 0},
    monitoring: "disabled",
    private_ip_address: "10.81.1.244",
    vpc_id: "vpc-07a5e160"
  }
]
```

How can I get just the DateTime back in my pipe so that I can `insert_all` my list? Or does this require multiple steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing code can be made to work with a little change, hope it fits your requirements:

```
things |> Enum.map(fn elem ->
  {:ok, datetime, _} = DateTime.from_iso8601(elem[:launch_time])
  Map.put(elem, :launch_time, datetime)
end)
```

Answer (score 1):

While one surely might `Enum.map/2`, the idiomatic and more flexible way would be to use `Access` behaviour ([`Access.all/0`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Access.html#all/0) for lists,) and [`Kernel.get_and_update_in/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html#get_and_update_in/3):

```
get_and_update_in(things, [Access.all(), :launch_time], fn prev ->
  {prev, with {:ok, neu, _} <- DateTime.from_iso8601(prev), do: neu}
end)
```

(or `(prev |> DateTime.from_iso8601() |> elem(1))`) if all the input data is proven to be valid.